# How to remove item from array when unchecking the checkbox usestate react hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Trying to write. a function that will remove item when unchecking the checkbox. It should iterate through the corresponding array and then remove the item.

```js
const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
    categories: [],
    colors: [],
    sizes: []
  });
  
  const _filterSection = (title: string, filterArray: string[]) => (
  <div className="filter-blocks">
    <h2 className="filter-title noselect" data-id={title}>{title}</h2>
    {filterArray.map((title, index) => (
      <FormCheckbox
        key={index}
        label={title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + title.slice(1)}
        onChange={(e) => _changeFilter(e.target.isChecked, title, e.target)}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
  
    const _changeFilter = (isChecked: boolean, title: string, value: string) => {
    let categoryName = value.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.getAttribute("data-id").toLowerCase();
    isChecked ? 
      setFilter({...filter, [categoryName]: [...filter[categoryName], title]}) : 
      setFilter({...filter, [categoryName]: [...filter[categoryName].filter(checkbox => checkbox != title)]})
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      {_filterSection("CATEGORIES", _categories)}
      {_filterSection("COLORS", _colors)}
      {_filterSection("SIZES", _sizes)}
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: If you can provide more context ( the code of the full React component), I might be able to come up with a solution.

Comment: check new updated snippet